# Azure SQL database - DacPac failing with error message

Tags: azure-sql-database, dacpac

We are facing the below error during dacpac deployment to Azure SQL Database.

> The type for column ID in table tablename is currently  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL but is being changed to  VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL. Data loss could occur and deployment may fail if the column contains data that is incompatible with type  VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL.

Below are the Parameters we are using

```
AdditionalArguments: '/p:AllowDropBlockingAssemblies=True /p:GenerateSmartDefaults=true /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=true /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions;PartitionFunctions;PartitionSchemes;Sequences;ExternalDataSources;ExternalTables'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is detailed discussed here, check suggestions: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11191

> > “Specifies that the operation will be terminated during the schema
> > validation step if the resulting schema changes could incur a loss of
> > data, including due to data precision reduction or a data type change
> > that requires a cast operation. The default (True) value causes the
> > operation to terminate regardless if the target database contains
> > data. An execution with a False value for BlockOnPossibleDataLoss can
> > still fail during deployment plan execution if data is present on the
> > target that cannot be converted to the new column type.”
>
> As a few other users have observed, you may have interdependencies
> involved in the deployment that need to be handled by a predeployment
> script or an additional property such as p:DropObjectsNotInSource or
> p:AllowDropBlockingAssemblies may cover your scenario.

As workaround, you may try to generate an update script [SqlPackage Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-script?view=sql-server-ver15).  You will see the same warning during the script generation but you may use this script to update your database.

Comment: Thanks for the link. We have gone through the github link that you shared and implemented the exact stuff mentioned in that link. if you look at my original question, all the options are mentioned. Many issues were resolved. However there are cases which were not resolved. Ex: Code: varchat(200) Not null to DB: nvarchar(max) NULL - these scenarios are throwing errors :-(

Comment: @Prawin `However there are cases which were not resolved.` yes, you are right. Your case is *a known issue* . We use **the Script action** and deploy the resulting script.